# Asterisk configuration, need to use a different internip for each trunk

Tags: asterisk

I'm currently configuring my asterisk server, that has two trunks, one for the incoming calls, one for the outgoing calls.

For each trunk, I would need to define a specific internip. So far, the IP used for both is the one defined as externip in the [asterisk] section.

Is there a way to enforce a different externip for only one of the two trunks ?

Answer (score 0):

Chan_SIP have no option for that.

Chan_PJSIP have transport section, each may have different ip(not tested).

```
[transport-udp-nat]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0
local_net=192.0.2.0/24
external_media_address=198.51.100.5
external_signaling_address=198.51.100.5

[transport-udp-nat2]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0:5061
local_net=127.0.0.1/32
external_media_address=198.51.100.6
external_signaling_address=198.51.100.6
```

Please note, that each transport have be on different ip/port(bind param).

You also can use pjsip for one address and chan_sip for other. Or you can start two asterisks on one host and connect it.